# Full height angular UI accordion

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make an Angular UI accordion full height no matter how big the content in the accordion groups is.

Se JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hanspc/TBz9F

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="caMain">
<div style="float: left; height: 100%; width: 300px; border-right: 1px solid #000">
<ca-accordion close-others="sidebar.oneAtATime">
    <ca-accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded"  is-open="sidebar.status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="sidebar.status.isFirstDisabled">
        This content is straight in the template.
    </ca-accordion-group>
    <ca-accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
        <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
    </ca-accordion-group>
    <ca-accordion-group is-open="sidebar.status.open">
        <ca-accordion-heading>
            I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': sidebar.status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !sidebar.status.open}"></i>
        </ca-accordion-heading>
        This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </ca-accordion-group>
</ca-accordion>
</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

</div>
```

I want the accordion to be my left column bar with height=100% (like the jQuery heightStyle=fill).

Can somebody show me how to do that? I've thought about rewriting the directive totally, but I think there must be a way to do with the original Accordion directive.
In my JSfiddle I've cloned the angular UI accordion directive (its called ca-accordion), but nothing is changed. Just to make it possible to add changes to the directive if needed.

Is the solution in Angular or just plain CSS (have tried that with no luck)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Solved it now.

I changed the UI accordion directive (created a new based on the source code and changed it).

Here's what I did:

1. Added a resize event on $window to my controller changing a simple boolean var every time the window size changed
2. Created a directive for the element containing the accordion (with height: 100%) with a watcher on the resize scope boolean. This triggered a function that read the height of the accordion container.
3. Added an extra accordion config option called fullHeight that can also be set using:`<ca-accordion full-height="true">`
4. Added ng-style="styles" to `<div class="panel-body" ng-style="styles" ng-transclude></div>`
5. added the following to the accordion controller:

   ```
   var fullHeight = angular.isDefined($attrs.fullHeight) ? $scope.$eval($attrs.fullHeight) : caAccordionConfig.fullHeight;

   // Create watcher for height changes if needed
   if(fullHeight){
       var that = this;
       $scope.$watch('screen.height', function(value) {
           that.height = value;
           that.panelHeight = that.calcHeight(value);
       });
   }

   this.calcHeight = function(screenHeight){
       var height = 0;
       height += $scope.sidebar.searchPanelHeight;

       for (var k=this.groups.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
           if(!this.groups[k].isOpen || 1 == 1){
               var tmpH = this.groups[k].returnHeight();
               height += tmpH;
           }
       }

       var panelHeight = screenHeight-height;
       $scope.sidebar.activePanelHeight = panelHeight;
       return panelHeight;
   };
   ```
6. Added a watcher + a function to return the height of the accordion panel to the accordionGroup directive:

   ```
           scope.returnHeight = function(){
               return element.find(".panel-heading").outerHeight(true);
           }

           // Watch for screen height changes
           scope.$watch(function() { return caAccordionCtrl['height']; }, function(value) {
               if ( value ) {
                   scope.styles = {
                       "height": caAccordionCtrl.panelHeight+"px"
                   }
               }
           });
   ```

So my solution was to clone the Angular UI accordion code and tweak it to my needs.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hanspc/TBz9F/

Comment: Hm, forgot to accept my own answer and now I can't? Can someone tell me why there's a two hour limit for that?